# Sequelize self-referential many-to-many; how to specify what I'm joining on

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize structure that associates my `User` table to itself through a `Follow` table, with `follower` and `following`. I'm 99% certain that I have all of the necessary pieces for this to be working the way I expect it to; I've the aliased

```
User.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.Follow, as: 'Followers', foreignKey: 'follower'});
User.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.Follow, as: 'Following', foreignKey: 'following'});
```

as well as

```
User.hasMany(models.Follow, { foreignKey: 'following' });
User.hasMany(models.Follow, { foreignKey: 'follower' });
```

and

```
Follow.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'following', as: 'Following' });
Follow.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'follower', as: 'Follower' });
```

And I'm able to call

```
User.findByPk(id, {
  include: {
    model: Follow
  }
});
```

which returns a single user and an array of Follow entries.
The problem I'm having is, Sequelize seems to be defaulting to creating the `Follow` query as `where: { followING: User.id }` rather than `where: followER`, such that if I have 1 user FOLLOWING themselves and 2 other people, but only FOLLOWED BY themselves, it only returns 1 result from my Follow table. As I was cycling through the primary keys for the handful of users in my seed, only the `following` value in my results change, such that I'm only ever returning a users' followers, not the other users that user is following.
Is there a way to specify in an `include` which specific column I'm trying to join on, when multiple columns match the Sequelize object to which I'm joining?
I understand that worst case scenario I can always skip the `User` step and go straight to

```
Follow.findAll({
  where: {
    follower: id
  }
})
```

But that restricts my immediate access to the User object and I'd have to write an additional query, which seems cumbersome considering a self-associated many-to-many capability exists.

Comment: I don't see an association like `User.hasMany(models.Follow`. How it's supposed to work at all?

Comment: @Anatoly I've edited my question - I did have two User.hasMany associations for Follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to get a user with followers or with following users you don't need to indicate `Follow` table. All you need is to indicate an alias of a required association:

```js
User.findByPk(id, {
  include: {
    model: User,
    as: 'Followers'
  }
});
User.findByPk(id, {
  include: {
    model: User,
    as: 'Following'
  }
});
```

In case you need to include `Follow` directly you need to add an associations like this:

```
User.hasMany(models.Follow, { as: 'FollowerLinks', foreignKey: 'follower'});
User.hasMany(models.Follow, { as: 'FollowingLinks', foreignKey: 'following'});
```

And you also should indicate an alias so that way Sequelize will know what association to use:

```js
User.findByPk(id, {
  include: {
    model: Follow,
    as: 'FollowerLinks'
  }
});
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include the User.hasMany associations as I already had them, but they're not aliased as you've suggested. You've solved me two problems with one answer here. Stellar.